How to loop through a nested object and delete objects where values of keys match
How do I loop through a nested object of the form
{
  'AAA': 
   { oldName: { index: 0, first: 'Bob', last: 'Hanson' },
     newName: { index: 0, first: 'Bob', last: 'Hanson' }
   }, 
  'BBB': 
   { oldName: { index: 1, first: 'Velma', last: 'Jones' },
     newName: { index: 2, first: 'Velma', last: 'Roberts'} 
   },
  'CCC': 
   { oldName: { index: 2, first: 'Jou', last: 'Xi' },
     newName: { index: 3, first: 'Jou', last: 'Xi' } 
   },
  'DDD': 
   { oldName: { index: 3, first: 'Betty', last: 'Ford' },
     newName: undefined},
  'EEE': 
   { oldName: undefined,
     newName: { index: 1, first: 'Fred', last: 'Tree' } 
  } 
}

and delete all the nested objects where for each first level key AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE
the value of the key oldName = the value of key newName
So, I end up with
{
 'BBB': 
   { oldName: { index: 1, first: 'Velma', last: 'Jones' },
     newName: { index: 2, first: 'Velma', last: 'Roberts' } 
   },
  'DDD': 
   { oldName: { index: 3, first: 'Betty', last: 'Ford' },
     newName: undefined },
  'EEE': 
   { oldName: undefined,
     newName: { index: 1, first: 'Fred', last: 'Tree' } 
   } 
}


Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(), and delete key in for loop

Just loop through the keys and delete when the full name hasn't changed:


const data = {
  'AAA': 
   { oldName: { index: 0, first: 'Bob', last: 'Hanson' },
     newName: { index: 0, first: 'Bob', last: 'Hanson' }
   }, 
  'BBB': 
   { oldName: { index: 1, first: 'Velma', last: 'Jones' },
     newName: { index: 2, first: 'Velma', last: 'Roberts'} 
   },
  'CCC': 
   { oldName: { index: 2, first: 'Jou', last: 'Xi' },
     newName: { index: 3, first: 'Jou', last: 'Xi' } 
   },
  'DDD': 
   { oldName: { index: 3, first: 'Betty', last: 'Ford' },
     newName: undefined},
  'EEE': 
   { oldName: undefined,
     newName: { index: 1, first: 'Fred', last: 'Tree' } 
  } 
}

for (const key in data) {
  const {oldName: a, newName: b} = data[key];
  a?.first === b?.first && a?.last === b?.last && delete data[key];
}

console.log(data);




Thank you; that is exactly what I needed! But I do not understand a?.first  the ? what is happening here?

@xyz333 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

You can filter the entries in data based on whether the first and last name fields are the same. This has the benefit (should it be desired) of leaving the original object intact.


const data = {
  'AAA': 
   { oldName: { index: 0, first: 'Bob', last: 'Hanson' },
     newName: { index: 0, first: 'Bob', last: 'Hanson' }
   }, 
  'BBB': 
   { oldName: { index: 1, first: 'Velma', last: 'Jones' },
     newName: { index: 2, first: 'Velma', last: 'Roberts'} 
   },
  'CCC': 
   { oldName: { index: 2, first: 'Jou', last: 'Xi' },
     newName: { index: 3, first: 'Jou', last: 'Xi' } 
   },
  'DDD': 
   { oldName: { index: 3, first: 'Betty', last: 'Ford' },
     newName: undefined},
  'EEE': 
   { oldName: undefined,
     newName: { index: 1, first: 'Fred', last: 'Tree' } 
  } 
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data)
    .filter(([_, v]) => v.oldName?.first != v.newName?.first || v.oldName?.last != v.newName?.last)
)

console.log(result)




If it's important in your domain, this way you keep the original object intact and don't need to care about side effects.

@Pipetus yes, that was my intention, and I've edited in a comment to that effect. It seems OP doesn't mind though.

use the for (const key in data) {} to get each rows and them compare the row data


const data = {
    'AAA': 
     { oldName: { index: 0, first: 'Bob', last: 'Hanson' },
       newName: { index: 0, first: 'Bob', last: 'Hanson' }
     }, 
    'BBB': 
     { oldName: { index: 1, first: 'Velma', last: 'Jones' },
       newName: { index: 2, first: 'Velma', last: 'Roberts'} 
     },
    'CCC': 
     { oldName: { index: 2, first: 'Jou', last: 'Xi' },
       newName: { index: 3, first: 'Jou', last: 'Xi' } 
     },
    'DDD': 
     { oldName: { index: 3, first: 'Betty', last: 'Ford' },
       newName: undefined},
    'EEE': 
     { oldName: undefined,
       newName: { index: 1, first: 'Fred', last: 'Tree' } 
    } 
  }
  


for (const key in data) {
    const {oldName, newName} = data[key];
    oldName?.first === newName?.first && oldName?.last === newName?.last && delete data[key];
}
  
console.log(data);



